# How to preseed installation whithout formatting and mounting a specific partition?

Tags: preseed

I want to make a  unattended installation of the Ubunbu Server 12.04 LTS using preseed.

My partition layout needs to create a partition without formatting and mounting it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a partman-auto/expert_recipe, but change the attributes for the partition you don't want to have formatted to method{ keep }.  You need to remove format{ }, filesystem{ }, and use_filesystem{ }.

You will also want to add the following lines to your preseed file:

```
partman-basicfilesystems partman-basicfilesystems/no_mount_point boolean false
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
```

Here's a link to the [example preseed file for Ubuntu 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt).  Example configuration is included there for several types of setups.

Comment: Thanks! I have found this params(specially no_mount_point) and the installation goes fine, although I use the filesystem{} and use_filesystem as well. Now I want to labeled the partition that is not mouted/formated in the unattended way. Do you know how

Comment: You should be able to use label{ mylabel } for the partition you are interested in labeling.

Comment: In the trusty the command: "ufw ufw/allow_known_ports multiselect SSH" do not work...